# Fading Background & Navigation Menu Are Getting In Each Others Way

Tags: jquery, menu, background, navigation, fading

my client is wanting a fading background image just under the horizontal drop-down navigation bar; the problem is, when you click on the navigation menu, any of the drop down items that is in the same location as the fading background area, they get hidden by the image. Is there a way to keep the navigation items atop the fading background?

I can't show it in here because the page says I have to have at least 10 posts to post an image since I'm new to the site but you can check it out here in action - http://metroanimalshelter.org/testredesigns2.html

Comment: The z-index of the closest parent element that is a sibling to the parent element that contains the image must be higher. Also, obligatory `<center> tag really?`

Comment: Set `position:relative` on your nav parent element and then give it a `z-index` higher than the image.  Done.

Comment: thanks Josh; yea this is all still very skeletal so I was just trying things out with the "center" tag lol wasn't planning on keeping it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a style attribute called z-index. You set one of the html forms to have z-index:-1 and the other one z-index:1 and the one with 1 will always be on top.

Comment: thank you Ivan; I've added my coding below in a comment; could you check it and see where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your nav bar a `z-index` value to pull it above your other content:

```
#ajonav {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Moobs; here's where I put it: 
#ajonav ul {
 background-color: #a01013; 
 padding: 0 0px;
 list-style: none;/*To remove the bullets*/
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}
 display: inline-block;
 }

but I still get the same issue- the nav menu drop down options are hidden by the fading background; am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to put it where I did (?)

Comment: Ok I must be doing something wrong; forgive me; getting over a concussion so things aren't always clicking as fast as they should: Here's what I did- #ajonav{ position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: auto;width: 90%;
}
/*

Comment: That should work. However I don't see that code in the CSS on the page you linked to. Where did you put it?

Comment: Sorry Moobs; I added the entire css code above; it was on a separate sheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sorry Moob; the CSS is on a separate sheet; here u go :
html, body {
background-color: #000000; 
margin: 0px; 
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif; 


font-size: small; 
line-height: 140%;
 background-color: #000000;    }




#maincont
{
        width:95%;
        margin:auto ;

padding:0px;
        text-align:left; background-color:#000000;

border:0px solid black;

}



#dbtech
{
    font-size:8px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}


#logo
{
    background-color: #6A9DFF; float:left;
    width:100%;;
    height:98px;
    min-height:98px;
}


#reloctext
{
    padding:2%;
    text-align:justify;

font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}


#reloctext ul li
{
    text-align:left;
}


#reloclogo
{
    float:right;
    padding:3% 2% 2% 2%;
}



#scroller
{
    float:left;
}


#erc{
    float:right;
    padding:2%;
}


#blurb{
    padding-bottom:2.5%;
}




#datebar
{
    float:left;
    background:#32aa1e url(http://i790.photobucket.com/albums/yy181/BirdmansArt/TuscAnimShelter/datebarimage-1.jpg);

    color:#000000;
    font-weight:bold;

    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
        display: inline;
}


#datebar a
{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#datebar a:hover {color : #F7DE0D; text-decoration: none; }



#bodytext
{
    float: left;
    width:98%;
    padding:0% 1% 0% 1%;

    background-color:#000000;

}


#bodytext2{
    float: left;
    width:90%;
    padding:0% 1% 0% 5%;

    background-color:#000000;

}


div.left
{
float:left;
width:20%;
padding: .5em;
border:0px ;
background: #4040ff ;
margin: 0em 3em 0em 0em;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: left;
}



.heading
{
    font-family:"Comic Sans MS";
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#0000FF;
}

.headingtwo
{
    font-family:"Comic Sans MS";
    font-weight:bold;
 font-size: 1.5em;  color:#1651CA;
width: 95%;}


.headingnav
{
    font-family:"Comic Sans MS";
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#0017a6;
}


.ital
{
     font-size: .8em;
    font-style:italic;
}


#trpic
{
    float:right;
    padding:2% 0% 0% 1%;
}


#trpic img
{
    border:1px solid black;
}



.rimg{

    float:right;
    padding:0% 0% 0% 1%;
}




.limg{

    float:left;
    padding:0% 2.4% 0% 0%;
}



#banner
{
    border:1px solid black;
}



#hours
{background: url(http://i790.photobucket.com/albums/yy181/BirdmansArt/TuscAnimShelter/bgforsite.jpg) no-repeat; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

    font-size:14px;
    text-align:center;}


#rightbar{background-color:#0066cc; height:100%;    float:left; width:20%;}






#bottom a
{
    color:#FFFFFF;}

/*
/********************* CSS For Navigation Menu *********************/
/* CSS Popout Menu */


#ajonav{margin: auto;width: 90%;
position: relative;
z-index: 50;
}
/*
 ******************************************************
 *Design the main ul
 ******************************************************
*/ 
 #ajonav ul {
 position: relative;
 background-color: #a01013; 
 padding: 0 0px;
 list-style: none;/*To remove the bullets*/
}
 display: inline-block;
 }

/*
 ************************************
 *Design the main ul li
 ************************************
*/
 #ajonav ul li {
 float: left;
 border-right: 1px solid #a01013;
 }
 #ajonav ul li:hover {
 background-color: #a01013;
 }
 #ajonav ul li:nth-child(5){border-right:none; }


#ajonav ul li:hover a {
  color: #efb009;
 }

 #ajonav ul li a {
  color: #E4E4E4; 
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  display: block;
  font-family: sans-serif,serif;
 }


/*
 ************************************
 *(Dropdown) Design the sub ul li
 ************************************
*/
/*
 ******************************************************
 *Hide the submenu ul at start
 ******************************************************
*/ 
 #ajonav ul ul{visibility:hidden;display: none;}
/*
 ******************************************************
 *Show the submenu when li gets hover
 ******************************************************
*/ 
 #ajonav ul li:hover > ul {

visibility:visible;display: block;}
 #ajonav ul ul {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #a01013;
 padding: 0px;

 }

 #ajonav ul ul li {
  position: relative;
  float: none; 
  border-top: 1px solid #727272;
 }

 #ajonav ul ul li a {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: #fff;
 } 

 #ajonav ul ul li a:hover {
color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #a01013;
 }


#info
{border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
background: url(http://i790.photobucket.com/albums/yy181/BirdmansArt/TuscAnimShelter/Infobg-1.jpg);
-moz-border-radius: 40px 40px 48px 48px}

#info,#info th, #info td 
{ border:3px solid color:#000000;

}

#info th
{height: 35px; background:#6B9CFF url(http://i790.photobucket.com/albums/yy181/BirdmansArt/TuscAnimShelter/AdditionalInfoShelterBg-2.jpg); text-align:center;
}

#info td
{text-align: left;
padding:3%;

}










/* fade slider */
.slides {
    height:300px;
    margin:50px auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
    width:900px;
}
.slides ul {
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;   


}

/* keyframes #anim_slides */
@-webkit-keyframes anim_slides {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    6% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    24% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    30% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes anim_slides {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    6% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    24% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    30% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}

.slides ul li {
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;

    /* css3 animation */
    -webkit-animation-name: anim_slides;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 24.0s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    -moz-animation-name: anim_slides;
    -moz-animation-duration: 24.0s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-direction: normal;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0;
    -moz-animation-play-state: running;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

/* css3 delays */
.slides ul  li:nth-child(2), .slides ul  li:nth-child(2) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6.0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6.0s;
}
.slides ul  li:nth-child(3), .slides ul  li:nth-child(3) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12.0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12.0s;
}
.slides ul  li:nth-child(4), .slides ul  li:nth-child(4) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18.0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18.0s;
}
.slides ul li img {
    display:block;
}

/* keyframes #anim_titles */
@-webkit-keyframes anim_titles {
    0% {
        left:100%;
        opacity:0;
    }
    5% {
        left:10%;
        opacity:1;
    }
    20% {
        left:10%;
        opacity:1;
    }
    25% {
        left:100%;
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        left:100%;
        opacity:0;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes anim_titles {
    0% {
        left:100%;
        opacity:0;
    }
    5% {
        left:10%;
        opacity:1;
    }
    20% {
        left:10%;
        opacity:1;
    }
    25% {
        left:100%;
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        left:100%;
        opacity:0;
    }
}

.slides ul li div {
    background-color:#000000;
    border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px #FFFFFF inset;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:26px;
    left:10%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:20px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    width:200px;

    /* css3 animation */
    -webkit-animation-name: anim_titles;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 24.0s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    -moz-animation-name: anim_titles;
    -moz-animation-duration: 24.0s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-direction: normal;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0;
    -moz-animation-play-state: running;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}









#bottom2 a
{
    color:#FFFFFF;}

/*
/********************* CSS For Navigation Menu *********************/
/* CSS Popout Menu */


#ajonav2{margin: auto;width: 90%;}
/*
 ******************************************************
 *Design the main ul
 ******************************************************
*/ 
 #ajonav2 ul {
 background: url(http://i790.photobucket.com/albums/yy181/BirdmansArt/TuscAnimShelter/BG2015_zpsf8c31554.jpg); 
 padding: 0 0px;
 list-style: none;/*To remove the bullets*/
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 }

/*
 ************************************
 *Design the main ul li
 ************************************
*/
 #ajonav2 ul li {
 float: left;
 border-right: 1px solid #a01013;
 }
 #ajonav2 ul li:hover {
 background: url(http://i790.photobucket.com/albums/yy181/BirdmansArt/TuscAnimShelter/BG2015_zpsf8c31554.jpg);
 }
 #ajonav2 ul li:nth-child(5){border-right:none; }


#ajonav2 ul li:hover a {
  color: #efb009;
 }

 #ajonav2 ul li a {
  color: #E4E4E4; 
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  display: block;
  font-family: sans-serif,serif;
 }


/*
 ************************************
 *(Dropdown) Design the sub ul li
 ************************************
*/
/*
 ******************************************************
 *Hide the submenu ul at start
 ******************************************************
*/ 
 #ajonav2 ul ul{visibility:hidden;display: none;}
/*
 ******************************************************
 *Show the submenu when li gets hover
 ******************************************************
*/ 
 #ajonav2 ul li:hover > ul {visibility:visible;display: block;}
 #ajonav2 ul ul {
 position: absolute;
 background: url(http://i790.photobucket.com/albums/yy181/BirdmansArt/TuscAnimShelter/BG2015_zpsf8c31554.jpg);
 padding: 0px;  
 }

 #ajonav2 ul ul li {
  position: relative;
  float: none; 
  border-top: 1px solid #727272;
 }

 #ajonav2 ul ul li a {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: #fff;
 } 

 #ajonav2 ul ul li a:hover {
color: #ffffff;
  background: url(http://i790.photobucket.com/albums/yy181/BirdmansArt/TuscAnimShelter/BG2015_zpsf8c31554.jpg);
 }


a:link  {color : #B71F1F ;}
a:visited {color : #800080; text-decoration : none;}
a:hover {color : #F7DE0D; text-decoration: none;}
a:active {color : #000000;}
```